I am trying to get extract comments using below code, but its not working


function extractComments(url) {
  // Fetch the HTML content of the website
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(htmlContent => {
      const comments = [];

      const htmlComments = htmlContent.match(//g) || [];
      const singleLineComments = htmlContent.match(/\/\/(.*?)\n/g) || [];

      comments.push(...htmlComments.map(comment => comment.slice(4, -3)));
      comments.push(...singleLineComments.map(comment => comment.slice(2, -1)));

      const elementComments = document.querySelectorAll(".comment-class p");

      comments.push(...Array.from(elementComments).map(comment => comment.innerText));

      return comments;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error("Error fetching or parsing comments:", error));
}

const websiteURL = "https://www.shopaholic.pk/storage-black-bag";
extractComments(websiteURL)
  .then(comments => {
    console.log("Extracted comments:");
    console.log(comments);
  });



i am trying to extract comments from this page Storage bag  but uper given code is not working...
someone please do help and suggest me some best practices. I am new programmer and also a student of software engineering.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

At a glance... extractComments doesn't return anything, so following it with .then() is likely to fail with a specific error.  You may have simply missed a return keyword before the fetch operation?

You're also missing a correct regex (//g) resulting in an error.
